# How to Create container in Docker

Tags: docker

I am new to docker. I have created a image in docker. When i try to create a container I am getting error. Don't know exactly how to create a container.
      My Dockerfile:

```
    FROM ubuntu:14.04
    RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
    RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install php5 php5-common php5-dev php5-json php5-mysql php5-cli php5-curl php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-readline apache2 libapache2-mod-php5
    ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
    ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
    ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
    RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
    RUN a2enmod rewrite
    EXPOSE 80
```

I have creates a image named test-image using this command:

```
   docker build -t test-image .
```

My docker images are: docker:images

```
      REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
    cli-image                               latest              245dbd83afa4        4 hours ago         421.3 MB
    test-image                              latest              245dbd83afa4        4 hours ago         421.3 MB
    pma                                     latest              073a46684e78        3 weeks ago         57.64 MB
    mysql                                   latest              14b396e4d628        3 weeks ago         156.3 MB
    debian                                  latest              1b01529cc499        3 weeks ago         125.1 MB
    ror                                     latest              dd1f2f09425e        3 weeks ago         778.5 MB
    alpine                                  3.3                 47cf20d8c26c        8 weeks ago         4.797 MB
    buildpack-deps                          jessie              877c36103ed7        10 weeks ago        619.5 MB
    tnqdockerregistry.com:5000/scrutinzer   latest              f7daff1a756f        6 months ago        96.28 MB
    vtool                                   latest              f726e6601c45        8 months ago        956 MB
    vtooljava                               latest              f726e6601c45        8 months ago        956 MB
    rmqimage                                latest              c6a9a19e3288        8 months ago        254.3 MB
    ubuntu                                  14.04               06ab2de020f4        8 months ago        187.9 MB
    hello-world                             latest              690ed74de00f        10 months ago       960 B
```

Now i want to create a container named testing-container for test-image.

I put this command to create the container:

```
   docker run -i -t test-image -d testing-container
```

I got this error:

```
   docker: Error response from daemon: Container command '-d' not found or does not exist..
```

I don't know how to do it.
can anyone tell me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: A good start is to read the docker documentation ...

Comment: I have posted the error @gonephishing

Comment: Yes, i refered, But getting error in creating a container. @Henry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dig into the error message from your command:

```
docker run -i -t test-image -d testing-container
```

After the image name, every following option/argument is passed to the container to run (or as an argument to your `ENTRYPOINT`). In the command above, `-t` requires no arguments, so `test-image` is your image name. This image is run as a container with the command `-d testing-container` and docker is correctly telling you that the executable `-d` was not found.

To run your container detached with the name testing-container, it's very similar to Maxim's command:

```
docker run -d --name=testing-container -p 8080:80 test-image
```

Note, however, that this won't work correctly because your Dockerfile has a few issues. The minor one is that you run `apt-get update` and `apt-get install` as separate `RUN` commands. With the caching, Docker won't rerun your update in the future even if you add new packages to install, and so you'll get errors if you try to add new packages to your install list. But the main error is that you didn't create a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT` to run, so your container will launch a shell in the background and immediately exit since there's no input to process (that could be given with the `-it` option, but you still wouldn't have a web server running).

Have a look through [docker's Apache Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/httpd/blob/12bf8c8883340c98b3988a7bade8ef2d0d6dcf8a/2.4/Dockerfile) for a better idea of how to write a Dockerfile without these issues. Or if your goal is to simply run Apache, you can [run their image directly from hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/httpd/).

Answer (score 0):

A very simple and easy creation can be created using this official link:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockerimages/

Answer (score 0):

Use [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) command.

Just for example:

```
docker run -t --name=testing-container -p <your-local-ip>:8080:80 test-image
```

ctrl+c

```
docker exec -it testing-container /bin/bash
root@3b9ff3f91a56:/# service apache2 restart
```

and go to `http://<your-local-ip>:8080` to check this out

Answer (score 0):

to create a container:
[image]
to start a contain
[image]
to create and start a container by one command:
[image]